# Как изменить настройки среды IDEA в файле "idea64.exe.vmoptions"?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

После добавления ошибочной строки в файл "idea64.exe.vmoptions" при запуске IDEA получаю экран с ошибкой "Start Failed". Но при попытке удалить эту строку из файла "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions" я не нахожу её там. Более того, я в этом файле не нахожу половины давно добавленных в него строк.
Вопрос: куда пропали эти строки и как удалить из настроек неверную запись, если она в файле отсутствует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный путь к файлу настроек под Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\<idea_ver>\idea64.exe.vmoptions
```

Для старых версий это может быть:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.<idea_ver>\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions
```

Comment: Увы, по этому пути у меня 7 директорий (в т.ч. "bin") и 4 файла (build.txt, Install-Windows-zip.txt, ipr.reg, product-info.json).

Comment: При открытии в стороннем редакторе в файле "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions" отсутствует половина строк, которые я в нём видел при открытии из IDEA.

Comment: В вашей версии немного другой путь - дополнил ответ